# Limit to the number of filter conditions

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I see in the ACS documents that there is a limit to the number of filter conditions specified.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters#defining-filters

The link calls out a limit of 16 MB for POST & 8 KB for the GET. We are using Azure SDK & so I assume the limit of 16 MB applies? What is the limit on the number of conditions that can be specified? (I understand that having a high number of conditions will affect the search perf)

Answer (score 2):

The SDK uses POST, so the 16 MB limit applies.

The limit on the complexity of filter expressions is implementation-dependent and subject to change because the way it's enforced depends on the implementation details of the service. Under the hood, it's a limit on the number of nodes in the abstract syntax tree (AST) of the parsed filter expression. The guidance from the documentation is that if your expression has hundreds of clauses, you're at risk of hitting the limit. Thinking of this limit in terms of clauses is a useful approximation of the actual AST-based limit implemented in the service. If you're contemplating having filters that large, you should rethink your approach.